# ERROR: (gcloud.preview) Invalid choice: 'docker'. Did you mean 'dm-v2'?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry, gcloud-cli

Somehow I was able to push my docker image to Google Container Registry with command:

```
    $ gcloud preview docker push gcr.io/<my-project-xxx>/<my-image-yyy>
```

I ran the commands yesterday and copied them to my notes, but today pasting them to terminal in the same order I get the error:

**ERROR: (gcloud.preview) Invalid choice: 'docker'. Did you mean 'dm-v2'?**

Why is that? where did teh "gcloud preview docker" command are then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [release notes](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/RELEASE_NOTES) 0.9.65 (2015/06/17):

> `gcloud preview docker` moved to `gcloud docker`.

---

The command was moved out of preview in the latest version of gcloud. You can run it with:

```
gcloud docker push gcr.io/<my-project-xxx>/<my-image-yyy>
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice to live on the edge.